# How do I set up a reverse dns on Ubuntu 12.04 VPS

Tags: networking, server, dns, mail, bind

As far as I can remember when setting up my VPS and mail server on it, I had configured the mail server correctly. However, a few of my clients get SMTP errors,

> host mx1.zonnet.nl[62.58.50.9] said: 553 We do not
> accept mail from IP addresses without reverse DNS. See
> http://wikipedia.org/wiki/reverse_dns (in reply to RCPT TO command)

So could anyone get me further to address whether I've configured it wrong or even worse: Not configured at all.

And of course: How to resolve it?

Oh, I see that I didn't had `BIND` installed, so that may help most of you.

Sadly, most tutorials I find are about different subjects, instead of resolving reverse DNS on Ubuntu 12.04 VPS.

Thanks!

Edit, extra: I'm seeing things such as

> Edit /etc/bind/named.conf.local and add the following:
>
> zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
>
> type master;
>
> file "/etc/bind/db.192";
>
> };

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html)

Where, 1.168.192, need to replaced with my networking IP, but what's my networking IP..? My IP(v4) is completely different than 1.168.192, which actually is 159.xxx.x.xxx.

Comment: You don't need BIND running on your system for reverse DNS lookups to work. It's going to be a function of the DNS records set up with your VPS provider that the domain maps back to a proper A Record and MX entries that match. Your primary domain checks out fine on the tools I run, so is this for another domain you're hosting?

Comment: Hey Douggro, all my domains have a dynamic dns. With fields such as www.DOMAIN.nl / imap.DOMAIN.nl, etc. They also all run on the same vps, so the experience for each domain should be equal. The only difference is that my mail server is configured with my own fqdn > main domain > iSCS.nl and through that mail configuration all domains go. However, I can't recreate the  error with my own mail account (iSCS.nl) but a few clients (one is verboonhoveniers.nl (info@...) which happens to have the error of rejected because no reverse dns. Thanks

Comment: Your SMTP server is giving your primary domain host in the SMTP banner, which is why the reverse DNS error is happening for the other domains. See if your VPS service supports PTR records, or change the MX record to point to the primary domain. I'm figuring that you got virtual domains figured out in Postfix to make this all work. ;)

Comment: Yes, I can change PTR records myself, which haven't been configured at all. To have a view of the dynamic DNS records, as well as the possible fields, check out this screenshot -> http://iscs.nl/dnsrecords.png - The below (filled in) fields. I think I don't need to clarify them. The above, empty fields, are the possible to be added fields. What should I  fill in the name and value fields of the PTR? Note: |Domain| = dynamic. whereas smtp.|domain|.nl for a domain as iSCS, would result in smtp.iscs.nl. Please use |domain|, unless all domains should point to a PTR record of my FQDN domain. Thanks

Comment: I believe the PTR record would have to be explicit to point to your system hostname that Postfix is using. Something like `mail.|DOMAIN| IN PTR iscs.nl` since Postfix is announcing itself as `220 iscs.nl ESMTP Postfix`

Comment: I've added a PTR record (this one -> http://iscs.nl/thiscorrect.png) - Can you check for (info@)verboonhoveniers.nl if it's correct (Don't check before 22:30 GTM+1) - Thans enormously mate!

Comment: Not sure that will work - can you switch the order the other way? Right now (14:53 PST) I'm not seeing a PTR record for either domain.

Comment: I've switched the fields and after looking at them again, it does makes more sense this way.. The ttl is 5 minutes, so they should update any moment, unless adding a record takes a few hours by itself, the first time, not regarding what ttl you set.

Comment: Depends on the upstream servers caching time for changes to propagate. Will keep checking.

Comment: That's not going to help. You're adding it to your domain's zone. It needs to be in your VPS provider's in-addr.arpa zone, which you can't modify at that page.